# Grails + Intellijj + spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I am working on writing some unit test for a grails app controller using spock. When I run the specification I get the following errors. 
Also all these errors are coming in the .java files. I am a newbie to grails and spock. Any help will be appreciated.
i am using jdk 1.8 , grails 2.4.3

```
Error:(14, 10) java: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)

Error:(14, 10) java: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)

Error:(14, 10) java: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
Error:(34, 23) java: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
Error:(79, 31) java: enhanced for loops are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
Error:(133, 41) java: ';' expected

Error:(171, 9) java: illegal start of expression
```

Comment: What is the version of JDK you are using? You must use JDK 6+ atleast. Are you also writing groovy syntax code in a .java file?

Comment: i am using jdk 1.8 , grails 2.4.3

Comment: You have to explicitly set the Project JDk in IntelliJ to use 1.8.

Comment: Ok. I changed the lanuage level to 8 in project strucutre dialog . That helped removing the errors. But not I am getting another error.

Comment: Its giving me 
Class not found : mytestclassControllerSpec

Comment: Have you named classes with lower case initial letters?

Comment: no they start with an upperCase